# I need a VBA function to count the working days between two dates

Tags: vba, function

I have this one:

```
Public Function WorkingDays(StartDate As Date, _
                        ByVal EndDate As Date, _
                        Optional ByVal Holidays As Range, _
                        Optional ByVal Workdays As Variant) As Long
Dim mpDays As Long
Dim mpHolidays As Variant
Dim mpWorkdays As Variant 
Dim i As Long
If Not Holidays Is Nothing Then mpHolidays = Application.Transpose(Holidays)
If IsMissing(Workdays) Then
    mpWorkdays = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Else
    mpWorkdays = Workdays
End If
For i = StartDate To EndDate

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Weekday(i), mpWorkdays, 0)) Then

        If IsError(Application.Match(i, mpHolidays, 0)) Then
            mpDays = mpDays + 1
        End If
    End If
Next i
WorkingDays = mpDays 
End Function
```

but it is very slow, 
I use this function in my Workbook and my sheet I've 130K records. How can it be improved?

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen that Excel has the NETWORKDAYS and the WORKDAYS functions?

Instead of looping through the dates from StartDate to EndDate which is very slow, why not work out the number of week days between the two dates and then loop through the holidays to see if each date falls between StartDate and EndDate?

Answer (score 0):

This link has formula version of Networkdays (without using the actual Networkdays function) and a VBA version:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/betternetworkdays.aspx

Comment: I did a test with two codes (my code and cpearson code) results: 00:02:38 vs 00:02:25 like 8% minus. 
result: good but I was hoping better.
thanks

Comment: I'd advise using the built in NETWORKDAYS function then - if you need to change the weekend use NETWORKDAYS.INTL.  That's got to be the fastest way.

Answer (score -1):

I change method to calculate work days, it's work in 00:00:32

```
Public Function WrkDaysCount(StartDate As Date, _
                        ByVal endDate As Date) As Long
Dim DayStart As Long
Dim DayEnd As Long
Dim daytot As Long
Dim Nrweeks As Long
DayStart = Weekday(StartDate, vbMonday)
DayEnd = endDate - StartDate + DayStart
Nrweeks = Int(DayEnd / 7)
daytot = DayEnd - (fest * 2) - DayStart + 1
WrkDaysCount = daytot

End Function
```

Comment: @Fabirizio - What is fest in the above code?