# Trying to obtain the difference between 2 dates (3 different cells)

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please help me to obtain the difference between 2 dates (working hours only, that's very important)

Take a look at this image:

[image]

**First response** is calculated by the difference between: Date First Response and Date of the problem

**Elapsed time** is calculated by the difference between: Date Last Response and Date of the problem

This is my macro so far (it is not working properly):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Const WORKING_DAY_START As String = "09:00"
Const WORKING_DAY_END As String = "18:00"
Const FORMULA_WORKING_TIME As String = _
    "=(INT(E2-D2)*(""" & WORKING_DAY_END & """-""" & WORKING_DAY_START & """)" & _
    "+MEDIAN(MOD(E2,1),""" & WORKING_DAY_END & """,""" & WORKING_DAY_START & """)" & _
    "-MEDIAN(MOD(D2,1),""" & WORKING_DAY_END & """,""" & WORKING_DAY_START & """))"
Const FORMULA_ELAPSED_TIME As String = "=F2-D2"
Dim lastrow As Long

    On Error GoTo ws_bdc_exit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Me

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'input Elapsed Time
        .Range("H2").Resize(lastrow - 1).Formula = FORMULA_ELAPSED_TIME

        'input First Response time
        .Range("G2").Resize(lastrow - 1).Formula = FORMULA_WORKING_TIME

        With .Range("G2:H2").Resize(lastrow - 1)
            .Value = .Value
            .NumberFormat = "##0.00"
        End With
    End With

ws_bdc_exit:
    Target.Offset(1).Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

EDIT #1: I should obtain working hours from Monday to Friday (weekend not included, but i dont know how to do it)

EDIT #2: The difference should be displayed in **hours**

EDIT #3: Before, i was using this macro (everything was working fine BUT i was not getting the working hours)

```
Public cVal
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim LastRow
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
t1 = TimeValue(CStr(Cells(i, "D").Value))
t2 = TimeValue(CStr(Cells(i, "E").Value))
t3 = TimeValue(CStr(Cells(i, "F").Value))

'input First Response time
If Hour(t2) - Hour(t1) = 0 Then
    Cells(i, "G").Value = Round((Minute(t2) - Minute(t1)) / 60, 2)
Else
    Cells(i, "G").Value = Hour(t2) - Hour(t1) + Round((Minute(t2) - Minute(t1)) / 60, 2)
End If

'input Elapsed Time
If Hour(t3) - Hour(t1) = 0 Then
    Cells(i, "H").Value = Round((Minute(t3) - Minute(t1)) / 60, 2) '- Cells(i, "J").Value - Cells(i, "J").Value
Else
    Cells(i, "H").Value = Hour(t3) - Hour(t1) + Round((Minute(t3) - Minute(t1)) / 60, 2) '- Cells(i, "J").Value
End If
Next i

Target.Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What, exactly does *it is not working properly* mean? Error message? wrong answer? computer goes up in smoke? Excel crashes?

Comment: Thank you for replying @RonRosenfeld !. Yeah, i am not getting the correct answer. I am not an expert and you know.. Also,i was not able to obtain ONLY the working  hours from Monday to Friday. Could you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function which should calculate the working hours, Mon-Fri, only.

Note that in your posted example, some of the dates are on Sat/Sun, so will calculate as zero.

The algorithm:

- Calculate workhours for each day that is Mon-Fri as being `WORKING_DAY_START -`WORKING_DAY_END` hours.
- Make an adjustment if the day happens to be the first or last day being calculated.

You can use this function either on the worksheet itself, you can call if from a Macro that fills in the cells with just the value.

Below I will show your original data, plus some extra lines altering your weekend work dates.

```
Option Explicit
Function elapsedWorkTime(startDT As Date, endDt As Date) As Date
    Const WORKING_DAY_START As Date = #9:00:00 AM#
    Const WORKING_DAY_END As Date = #6:00:00 PM#
    Dim adjTimeStart As Date, adjTimeEnd As Date, totTime As Date
    Dim D As Date

For D = DateValue(startDT) To DateValue(endDt)
    Select Case Weekday(D)
        Case 2 To 6
            'Adj for first and last days
            If D = DateValue(startDT) Then
                If TimeValue(startDT) <= WORKING_DAY_START Then
                    adjTimeStart = 0
                ElseIf TimeValue(startDT) >= WORKING_DAY_END Then
                    adjTimeStart = WORKING_DAY_START - WORKING_DAY_END
                Else
                    adjTimeStart = WORKING_DAY_START - TimeValue(startDT)
                End If
            End If

            If D = DateValue(endDt) Then
                If TimeValue(endDt) >= WORKING_DAY_END Then
                    adjTimeEnd = 0
                ElseIf TimeValue(endDt) <= WORKING_DAY_START Then
                    adjTimeEnd = WORKING_DAY_START - WORKING_DAY_END
                Else
                    adjTimeEnd = TimeValue(endDt) - WORKING_DAY_END
                End If
            End If

            totTime = totTime + WORKING_DAY_END - WORKING_DAY_START
    End Select
Next D

elapsedWorkTime = totTime + adjTimeStart + adjTimeEnd

End Function
```

**EDIT** Corrected formatting on screenshot

Note that the formula in the worksheet cell, since you want the output expressed as hours, is something like:

```
=elapsedWorkTime(C2;D2)*24
```

[image]

Note the discrepancy for `5541`.  In your example, you show a value of `8,52` for elapsed time.  But in your requirements statement you write you want to include working hours only.  Working hours end at `18:00` so time spent after that should not be counted.

Comment: Thank you for replying!
Gonna check it out, dude :)

Comment: Sorry, i was not able to make it work. What is your worksheet? :/

Comment: Could you please help me with this: "You can use this function either on the worksheet itself, you can call if from a Macro that fills in the cells with just the value." I am a little confused :/

Comment: Also, output should be displayed in hours only. i.e: 0,5 hours = 00:30. Do you get me?

Comment: Do  note that *Date of the problem, Date First Response and Date of the problem* are entered manually (with the corresponding time)

Comment: @programming_always The output will be as Excel time.  If you want to change it to hours and fractions of an hour, just do the usual multiplication and format however you want.

Comment: @programming_always What is confusing about the term *use this function*?  When you use a function on the worksheet, you enter it into a cell on the worksheet.  If you use a function from a macro, you use it within the macro.

Comment: @programming_always You use this like any function.  For example, if you have it on the worksheet, and your start date/time and end date/time are in `c3` and `d3`, you would enter like `F3: =elapsedWorkTime(C3,D3)`.  Also, please see the edit of the screenshot.  I had the date/times incorrectly formatted.

Comment: Yeah, i get it now.. i feel a little stupid :/.
Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is no need to use VBA.

1. Use NETWORKDAYS function to count workdays between dates.
2. Multiply them by working hours a day
3. Substract work hours from begin and end date (e.g. work started later than workday begins and so on)
4. Calculate totals.

I'd recommend to do every step in a single cell, in order to check step-by-step logics.

Comment: Thank you for replying!
Could you please help me to modify it?

Comment: Anyway,i need to use VBA

Comment: Is this a study task to use VBA? Actually it is bad customer if he dictates architecture of the solution. He needs only the solution, realization details - your responsibility area

Comment: Yeah, i get you but i need to do it because VBA is required :/]

Comment: Do you know VBA?

Comment: Call this function from VBA Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(#2/1/2010#, #10/12/2010#)?

Comment: Or stufy related topics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322689/i-need-a-vba-function-to-count-the-working-days-between-two-dates

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I need to modify my code :/